# Optimal way to choose less or greater operator before loop

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization

I have two arrays comprising x,y vales for y=f(x). I would like to provide a function that finds the value of x that corresponds to either the min or max sampled value of y.

What is an efficient way to select proper comparison operator before looping over the values in the arrays?

For example, I would like to do something like the following:

```
double FindExtremum(const double* x, const double* y,
                    const unsigned int n, const bool isMin) {
   static std::less<double>    lt;
   static std::greater<double> gt;
   std::binary_function<double,double,bool>& IsBeyond = isMin ? lt : gt;
   double xm(*x), ym(*y);
   for (unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i, ++x, ++y) {
      if (IsBeyond()(*y,ym)) {
         ym = *y;
         xm = *x;
     }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, the base class `std::binary_function` does not define a virtual operator().

Will a compiler like g++ 4.8 be able to optimize the most straight forward implementation?

```
double FindExtremum(const double* x, const double* y,
                    const unsigned int n, const bool isMin) {
   double xm(*x), ym(*y);
   for (unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i, ++x, ++y) {
      if ( ( isMin && (*y<ym)) ||
           (!isMin && (*y>ym)) ) {
         ym = *y;
         xm = *x;
     }
   }
}
```

Is there another way to arrange things to make it easy for the compiler to optimize? Is there a well known algorithm for doing this?

I would prefer to avoid using a templated function, if possible.

Comment: What is `min` in both of your examples?

Comment: @0x499602D2 - thanks, changed `min` to `isMin`

Comment: *I would prefer to avoid using a templated function, if possible.* Why?

Comment: @DavidHammen - I was hoping to learn a bit about compiler optimization and whether there was a known "best way" for doing this in a single function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to pass the comparison functor as a templated function parameter, e.g.

```
template <typename Compare>
double FindExtremum(const double* x, const double* y,
                    const unsigned int n, Compare compare) {
   double xm(*x), ym(*y);
   for (unsigned int i=0; i<n; ++i, ++x, ++y) {
      if (compare(*y,ym)) {
         ym = *y;
         xm = *x;
     }
   }
}
```

Then if you need runtime choice, write something like this:

```
if (isMin) {
    FindExtremum(x, y, n, std::less<double>());
} else {
    FindExtremum(x, y, n, std::greater<double>());
}
```

Avoiding a templated function is not really possible in this case. The best performing code will be one that embeds the comparison operation directly in the loop, avoiding a function call - you can either write a template or write two copies of this function. A templated function is clearly the better solution.

Comment: This is the way most of STL algorithms are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

For ultimate efficiency, make the comparison operator or the comparison operator choice a template parameter, and don't forget to **measure**.

When striving for utmost micro-efficiency, doing virtual calls is not in the direction of the goal.

That said, this is most likely a case of *premature optimization*, which Donald Knuth described thusly:

> “Premature optimization is the root of all evil”

(I omitted his reservations, it sounds more forceful that way. :-) )

Instead of engaging in micro-optimization frenzy, which gains you little if anything, and wastes your time, I recommend more productively trying to make the code as clear and provably correct as possible. For example, use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays and separately passed sizes. And, for example, don't call the boolean comparison operator `compare`, as recommended in another answer, since that's the conventional name for tri-valued compare (e.g. as in `std::string::compare`).

Comment: It's certainly premature optimization. :) I mainly wanted to see if there was a standard algorithm for this, since it seems like a situation that must have come up a lot.

Comment: @Corey - Yes, it comes up a lot. That's one of the many reasons that generic programming was invented. Why do you want a non-templates function when that is exactly what the doctor ordered?

Comment: @DavidHammen - See my comment above in the opening question. Mainly because I wanted to see if there was a more clever solution that I hadn't thought of. :)

Answer (score 1):

Some questions arise here. First, I think you're overcomplicating the situation. For example, it would be easier to have two functions, one that calculates the min and other that calculates the max, and then call either of them depending on the value of `isMin`.

More so, note how **in each iteration** you're making the test to see if `isMin` is true or not, (at least in the "optimized" code you show last) and that comparison could have been done **just once**.

Now, if `isMin` can be deduced in any way at compile time, you can use a template class that selects the correct implementation optimized for the case, and without any run-time overhead (not tested, written from memory):

```
template<bool isMin>
class ExtremeFinder
{
static float FindExtreme(const double* x, const double* y,
                    const unsigned int n)
{
    // Version that calculates when isMin is false
}
};

template<>
class ExtremeFinder<true>
static float FindExtreme(const double* x, const double* y,
                    const unsigned int n)
{
    // Version that calculates when isMin is true
}
};
```

and call it as `ExtremeFinder<test_to_know_isMin>::FindExtreme(...);`, or, if you cannot decide it at compile time, you can always do:

```
if (isMin_should_be_true)
   ExtremeFinder<true>::FindExtreme(...);
else
   ExtremeFinder<false>::FindExtreme(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had 2 disjunct criteria, e.g. `<` and `>=`, you could use a `bool less` function argument and use XOR in loop:

```
if (less ^ (a>=b))
```

Don't know about performance, but is easy to write.

Or not-covering-all-possibilities-disjunct `<` and `>`:

```
if ( (a!=b) && (less ^ (a>b) )
```